# Accidently Moved Downloads to a Full Drive, Can't Move it Back

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems, file-transfer

So, I made a mistake while moving the downloads folder, and now the Downloads folder *is* the drive. I can't move it because you can't move a full drive, so I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In this drive, make a new Folder.

Now move the Contents of Downloads (files outside of this new folder) to the new folder.

Once this is done, you can move (copy) New Folder back to your home Downloads folder.

In general, you can move files into an arbitrary folder and then move (copy) this arbitrary folder wherever you wish.

Also Copy from / to and verify before deleting the from location if you wished to move files / folders.

If, during the initial error, you changed the Properties of Downloads, you can change the location. This is not moving any files.

Select Downloads, right click on it to select Properties, then location and change it.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "home Downloads folder"?

Comment: On the "new" Drive, make a folder, move the files into this folder. Now move (copy) this folder to the Drive containing the real "Downloads" folder. Once you have the files in question safely inside a good folder, you can copy them where you need to.

Comment: I can copy the things I've downloaded into the new file, but that doesn't change the fact that new downloads go to the drive.

Comment: You can change the location of Downloads. I amended my answer,

Comment: I have tried to, but it won't let me because it thinks I'm moving the whole drive.

Comment: Make a different user Account, make sure it is a member of Administrators, log into the new Account, and try assigning the folder location from the new account. I am not sure what you might have done and hope the problem is not too severe. The methods I posted work in the significant majority of cases.